# NVIDIA GeForce 410M Error

Tags: nvidia

I bought a new Sony laptop, I3-2350M Processor 2.30 GHz, and I have a problem while opening splinter cell conviction. It appears to me a screen shows the following thing :
Video card : NVIDIA GeForce 410M not supported

and when I click yes to continue, a black page appears and nothing works.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like as if the game is too intense for your graphics card (after looking at a trailer, even mine wouldn't be able to run it ^_^)

Comment: @lkjoel You might consider expanding that into an answer.

Comment: Well it isn't a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card is not capable enough for the game. I doubt that using a low graphics setting would help (if it even exists), and if it could, I don't know whether it would be possible to change the configuration file or not.

And don't feel bad about your graphics card, mine isn't capable enough either ;). If you really want to play the game, try getting a better one (Radeon HD 6950-6970 seems like a good option, since it is around $200-400, and is very powerful)